# How to compile a C++ program using .NET Framework compilers at command line.?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

i want to compile a c++ program using .NET2.0 compiler.
so i navigate to c:\windows\Microsoft.Netframework\2.0.57\ and uses csc compiler to compile.

It shows lot of errors.

But it compiles csharp file. But in visual studio it compiles. so i think that in visual studio c++ copiler installed i think so.

#### filename test.cpp

using namespace System;

```
class test

{

   void disp()

   {

      Console::WriteLine("Hello");
   }

 };

 void main()
 
{
   
  test *t=new test();
   
   t->disp();

}
```

so plz tell me is it possible to compile c++ file using .net framework 2.0 based comiler at command prompt  and how?

Answer (score 3):

`csc` is the C# compiler, so you shouldn't be surprised that it doesn't compile C++.

Use `cl` (the C++ compiler) with the `/clr` switch to compile C++/CLI code. Alternatively, if you've got a solution/project file, use `msbuild`.

Note that the C++ compiler doesn't ship with .NET, unlike the C# compiler.

Comment: Where can I get the `cl.exe` without installing Visual Studio?

Comment: @JinKwon: No idea, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JinKwon You can install `Build Tools for Visual Studio`. It contains bunch of command-line tools useful for build servers. You can pick required components (like c++ compiler) and it doesn't come with Visual Studio itself. Note, that it may require Visual Studio license anyway. In the moment you can download it [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) (bottom of page)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a huge surprise that the C# compiler doesn't like the C++ code; you might as well feed it vb / java / whatever - it isn't going to be legal.

To compile C++, you'll need the C++ compiler, perhaps from C++ Express Edition. Note that for this to compile into mixed/IL it'll been to be managed C++.

Comment: You two should merge to one super hero :)

Comment: sounds painful... and our families might object (maybe, maybe not)

Comment: "By your powers combined I am Captain Planet."

Answer (score 0):

csc is the compiler for csharp, not C++

The easiest way to compile from the command line is to use msbuild, and pass it the name of your project (or solution file).