# Excel AddIn Click Once deployment issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, office-interop, excel-addins

When I create a Excel 2010 Add-in project in Visual Studio 2010, and configure my prerequisite publish options for click once deployment, the 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64) option item, has a warning indicator over the icon, which screen tip says "Prerequisite could not be found for bootstrapping". Once I try to publish, it publishes fine, however, I get the warning:

```
"Item 'Microsoft.VSTORuntime.4.0' could not be located in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\'."
```

I've tried re-installing the VSTO 4.0 Runtime to resolve this with no luck. Any ideas how to fix this warning?

[image: New Project]

[image: Prerequisites]

[image: Warning]
**Update**
After uninstalling VS11, and repairing VS2010, then uninstalling VS2010, and re-installing, I now have these issues:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got Visual Studio 11 installed, bootstrapper should be here 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper

I got VS2010 with Windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: I do, I had installed the beta a few months back. Maybe I should try repairing my VS2010 installation? Thoughts?

Comment: May be good idea to first uninstall your VS2011 and dotnet 4.5 and try again if not then repair/reinstall VS2010

Comment: Thanks, I've uninstalled VS11, and I'll try repairing VS2010 in the morning to see if that resolves it.

Comment: I did a repair on VS2010, and now I have three new error when trying to publish. Missing binaries for VSTO4, Windows Installer, and .Net 3.5SP1. I'm going to do an Uninstall and Re-Install of VS2010. I think that should definitely resolve these new issues, and hopefully fix my main issue.

Comment: I have more issues now, see updated screenshot in the question.

Comment: OMG this is really annoying errors with BootStrapper. I found these blogs from google search. http://netpl.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-on.html

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to uninstall .net 4.5. I'll do that and re-try everything, and re-install VS2010 or repair to see if that does it. This post also has a reference to that fixing a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593340/msbuild-error-msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin

Comment: Uninstalling .net 4.5 did the trick. Now I can publish without any warnings. Now my only issue (not completely related), is that my Excel AddIn is now no longer loading in Excel. This may be related, but is not exactly related to the publish issue.

Comment: I posted my new issue here, not sure if you have any insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287007/excel-wont-open-launch-vsto-addin-when-running-in-debug-mode-of-visual-studio-2