# VS 2017 Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in csproj folder

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

When i try to build a project using MSBuil tools for VS2017 an error occurred Could not find required file 'setup.bin'

Comment: See if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499092/error-msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin-publish-to-local-failure?rq=1. I'd also recommend putting effort in your question, it's in a state where no one would be able to help you out; how did you get the error? Is there any specific error code? Any screenshots or how to reproduce it? Update your question, please, especially if this link didn't help you either (how didn't it help you?)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I solved the problem re-installing VS2015 i think the has to do with the previous version of VS unnistaller. Seems to be removing folders that eventually are necessary to VS2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I solved the problem re-installing VS2015 i think the has to do with the previous version of VS unnistaller. Seems to be removing folders that eventually are necessary to VS2017