# Error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin' while building Wix Installer

Tags: wix

I am trying to build a Wix installer for my project in Visual Studio 2015.

I have Wix Toolset 3.10.3.3007 installed.

Got this error, Looks like I need some kind of bootstrapper for Windows 8.1A.

**1. What is "A" in 8.1 and Where do I find 8.1A SDK so that I get Bootstrapper Engine.**

```
   1>------ Build started: Project: Y, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
    1>C:\X\Y.wixproj(56,5): error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Engine'.
    1>Done building project "Y.wixproj" -- FAILED.
    1>
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am not sure why wix project is pointing to Windows 8.1 SDK. I am running Windows 10.

I already have Windows 8.1 & 10 SDKs installed here -

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593340/msbuild-error-msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin).

> You could try installing the .NET Framework SDK or manually set it up by copying the files and adding the registry entries.