# Visual Studio Install the barebones to run a project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a .net poject (wpf, excel and asp.net site), I also have a build machine for the purpose of continuous integration. For continuous integration to work, I need to be able to build the project. So, what I have done so far is install visual studio on a build machine and things will build fine, but I dont really have that option, so I was wondering what do I need to run from the visual studio setup, just to be able to build projects, meaning  I am pretty sure some of things like f# in this case or MVC frameworks are not something that I need. Is it possible to run a few of the executable or just customize the install and if so what are the mandatory things that I need to select to basically boil down to having a solution be able to build and not have the ide installed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**MSBuild** is the component that builds your solutions. You can have a look at this question to run it with minimal installation:

[Installing MSBuild 4.0 without Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567018/installing-msbuild-4-0-without-visual-studio-2010?rq=1)

Comment: I tried running windows sdk on the build machine and it keeps failing

Comment: is their anyway around that? Its perferrable that I dont install Visual Studio.

Comment: run the install and it is unsuccesfull

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing the specific reason, but if you manage to complete the installation of SDK successfully, you will be able to run it without installing VS.